# How to wait for button in uia automation using powershell

Tags: powershell, ui-automation

Currently i want to wait to see if a button is enabled in a window i can see many wait commandlet are supported by uiautomation.dll . but could not make it work inside the window. command i am trying.

Working code for wait for window

```
Wait-UIAwindow -name "WindowMessageBox"
```

Not working inside window when i wait for button

```
Get-UIAwindow -name "WindowMessageBox" | Wait-uiabuttonisenabled -automationid "ButtonID"
```

any help to get result as button is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
Get-UiaButton -AutomationId '1001' -Class 'Button' -Name 'Browse...' | Wait-UiaButtonIsEnabled  -Seconds 3000| Invoke-UIAButtonClick
```

This worked for me, there is no `-automationid` parameter for `Wait-uiabuttonisenabled` so have to work around with pipelining it in my code instead of  `Invoke-UIAButtonClick` you can place `( Get-UIAwindow -name "WindowMessageBox" )`

Comment: Please edit your answer, so that the readability is improved. Mark code as such and write the first char of a new sentence capitalized.